# Strange behavior with Python 3 re.sub

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

The following code:

```
import re
print(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', ',Inc.', re.IGNORECASE).lower())
print(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', ', Inc.', re.IGNORECASE).lower())
```

produces:

```
inc
inc.
```

https://repl.it/repls/RightThankfulMaintenance

Why?

Comment: The fourth parameter to `re.sub` is count, not flags. It should be `re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', ',Inc.',0, re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: Knew I was forgetting something silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [doco](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=sub#re.sub), the `re.sub` signature is:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

So, let's examine your call based on that:

```
re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ''    , ', Inc.', re.IGNORECASE) # default
#       <  pattern  >  <repl>  <string>  <   count   >    <flags>
```

You are passing the *flag* `re.IGNORECASE` (it has the value `2` if you `print(int(re.IGNORECASE))`, though I suspect that's not mandated anywhere) as the *count* to use.

So it only does up to two substitutions, which is the comma and the space at the start in your second example. It *also* did that in your first example, it's just that there was only one character that matched rather than three, so you didn't notice.

Instead, you should use:

```
>>> re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', ', Inc.', flags=re.IGNORECASE).lower()
'inc'
```